# Burninate [discussion-board] and cleanse all its questions with righteous fire

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[discussion-board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion-board) looks like a mess. Of its 29 total questions, 15 (**50%**) have nothing obvious to do with discussion boards. Of the remainder, 11 appear to be about SharePoint discussion boards. The other 3 relate to building discussion boards with other technologies.

That's 15 crappy questions (trust me, I checked) that need the tag removed.  The 11 SharePoint questions could use a new tag like [sharepoint-discussion-boards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-discussion-boards) with less ambiguity. The other 3 - do they really need a tag to say that they're building a discussion board?

[image]

Comment: 15 out of 29 isn't actually 50%; it's about 51.72%.

Comment: @Alex Actually, it's 51.724137931034482758620689655172%. But 50% `1` is close enough, `2` sounds better.

Comment: 4 years later, it's done.